# How to check if sum of 3 integers in list matches another integer? (python)

Tags: python, algorithm

Here's my issue:

I have a large integer (anywhere between 0 and 2^32-1). Let's call this number X.
I also have a list of integers, unsorted currently. They are all unique numbers, greater than 0 and less than X. Assume that there is a large amount of items in this list, let's say over 100,000 items.

I need to find up to 3 numbers in this list (let's call them A, B and C) that add up to X. 
A, B and C all need to be inside of the list, and they can be repeated (for example, if X is 4, I can have A=1, B=1 and C=2 even though 1 would only appear once in the list).

There can be multiple solutions for A, B and C but I just need to find one possible solution for each the quickest way possible.

I've tried creating a for loop structure like this:

```
For A in itemlist:
  For B in itemlist:
    For C in itemlist:
      if A + B + C == X:
        exit("Done")
```

But since my list of integers contains over 100,000 items, this uses too much memory and would take far too long.

Is there any way to find a solution for A, B and C without using an insane amount of memory or taking an insane amount of time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: you can use a `while index1 < len(itemList):` structure and have 3 variables `index1,index2,index3` and increment those variables instead of iterating through the list. this way you only need to allocate more space for those variables

Comment: You may try to first sort the lists, and `break` the current for nested loop if `A + B > X` (in the second `for`) or if `A + B + C > X` (in the third one). By doing so, you may save some calculations, it is like a backward algorithm. However, I am not sure it will really perform better.

Comment: You can create a temp variable that contains a+b before entering the last loop. Avoiding recalculating A+B.

Comment: Note: if your list is [1,2,3] and your target is 9, your current loop will find an answer saying 3+3+3 is 9, even though 3 is only in your list once. For that reason, you should consider using `itertools.combinations` as @inspectorG4dget recommended.

Comment: @RobertB That's acceptable though, I'm allowed to repeat items in my list even if they only appear once.

Comment: @JonWarren that actually changes the problem from what you stated. You stated 3 items in the list.

Comment: @RobertB I apologize, I thought what I had parenthesized in the second paragraph explained that enough, I'll try and edit that part to make it more understandable!

Comment: Why not try a non-comparative sort like Radix Sort? That would have a bit of memory overhead but at least it'd run O(N) for every case, then you can use a more optimized algorithm for finding A, B and C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can reduce the running time from n^3 to n^2 by using set something like that

```
s = set(itemlist)
for A in itemlist:
    for B in itemlist:
        if X-(A+B) in s: 
            print A,B,X-(A+B)
            break
```

you can also sort the list and use binary search if you want to save memory

Comment: I'm not sure this is O(n^2). The "in" statement testing for set inclusion inside the doulble loop is not constant time. Perhaps it is O( (n^2) logn).

Comment: set is implemented using hash table which provide O(1) lookup time in operator here make use of the hash table

Comment: @RobertB I think `in` for `set` is O(1) because values access is amortized thanks to hash values. Which is why this answer is very clever.

Comment: According to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity it is best case O(1) and worst case O(n), which, for a large set such as this, I was saying perhaps O(log n) is a better approx. But it is better than O(n^3) in any case so ...

Comment: Did a practical test. Even with n=100,000 the `in` statement is lightning quick, so I'm in the wrong.

Comment: @RobertB: You're not strictly wrong, it's just that the best case behavior is very common. You need a carefully crafted set of non-equal values that have the same hash to get O(N) performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

nums = collections.Counter(itemlist)
target = t  # the target sum
for i in range(len(itemlist)):
    if itemlist[i] > target: continue
    for j in range(i+1, len(itemlist)):
        if itemlist[i]+itemlist[j] > target: continue
        if target - (itemlist[i]+itemlist[j]) in nums - collections.Counter([itemlist[i], itemlist[j]]):
            print("Found", itemlist[i], itemlist[j], target - (itemlist[i]+itemlist[j]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from @inspectorG4dget's code, this has two modifications:

1. If `C < B` then we can short-circuit the loop.
2. Use `bisect_left()` instead of `collections.Counter()`.

This seems to run more quickly.

```
from random import randint
from bisect import bisect_left

X = randint(0, 2**32 - 1)
itemset = set(randint(0,X) for _ in range(100000))
itemlist = sorted(list(itemset))    # sort the list for binary search
l = len(itemlist)

for i,A in enumerate(itemlist):
    for j in range(i+1, l):         # use numbers above A
        B = itemlist[j]
        C = X - A - B               # calculate C
        if C <= B: continue    
        # see https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists
        i = bisect_left(itemlist, C)
        if i != l and itemlist[i] == C:
            print("Found", A, B, C)
```

To reduce the number of comparisons, we enforce `A < B < C`.